# how to replace dictionary after translating dataframe columns using google cloud v2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df_en = df_por.copy()
translations = {}
target= 'en'
for column in df_en[['review_comment_title','review_comment_message']]:
    unique_elements = df_en[column].unique()
    #print(len(unique_elements))
    for element in unique_elements:
        translations[element] = translate_client.translate(element, target)
print(translations)
```

When i print the dictionary it work fine.

```
output:
{'No Review': {'translatedText': 'No Review', 'detectedSourceLanguage': 'en', 'input': 'No Review'}, 'recomendo': {'translatedText': 'I recommend', 'detectedSourceLanguage': 'pt', 'input': 'recomendo'},
```

But when i try to replace in the dataframe. The values are not changed/translated. I need 'translatedText' from the dictionary

using this command

```
    df_en.replace(translations, inplace = True)

    df_en.head()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the result of df_en.head()?

Comment: The dict is nested.  Probably you need to create another dict with simple mapping.

Comment: @PabloLópez  I have added the picture. its not translated in english. No review and NO message are built-in in english language. translation required  from purtoguise to english

Answer (score 0):

If you have this dataframe:

```py
  review_comment_title review_comment_message
0            No Review             No Message
1            No Review             No Message
2            No Review              recomendo
3            No Review              recomendo
```

and this dictionary of translations:

```py
translations = {
    "No Review": {
        "translatedText": "No ReviewXXX",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "en",
        "input": "No Review",
    },
    "recomendo": {
        "translatedText": "I recommend",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "pt",
        "input": "recomendo",
    },
}
```

Then:

```py
df.replace(
    {k: v["translatedText"] for k, v in translations.items()}, inplace=True
)
print(df)
```

Will change the dataframe to:

```
  review_comment_title review_comment_message
0         No ReviewXXX             No Message
1         No ReviewXXX             No Message
2         No ReviewXXX            I recommend
3         No ReviewXXX            I recommend
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help I really appreciate that. (Y)